# text align : center in a textfield in flutter

Tags: flutter, textfield

I want to make the text be written at the center of the container but it keeps being at the bottom.

```
Container(
    width: 250.yswx,
    padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 5.yswx),
    child: Center(
        child: TextField(
            textAlignVertical: TextAlignVertical.center,
            textAlign: TextAlign.center,
            style: TextStyle(
                 color: Colors.black,
                 fontSize: 13.yswx
            ),
            cursorColor: Colors.black,
            decoration: InputDecoration(
                 border: InputBorder.none,
                 hintText: widget.placeHolder,
                 hintStyle: TextStyle(
                     color: Color(0xffbfbfbf),
                     fontSize: 13.yswx
                 )
             ),
        ),
    ),
);
```

the result:

[image]

Comment: are you using this textfield inside row ?

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps:

```
TextField(
      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
      decoration: InputDecoration(
        hintText: "Testing Centered",
      ),
```

[image]